# Can Gameboy Printer be used with Gameboy Advance?

Tags: game-boy-advance, game-boy-printer

My younger sibling recently bought a Gameboy Printer so that he could print out his Pokemon on Pokemon Gold and Yellow. However, once it came we realized that the Ext.1 port (where you plug the cord in) on the Printer was not the same as on his GBA. I have a Gameboy Link Cable (which plugged into the Printer and not the GBA) as well as a Gameboy Advance Link Cable (which plugged into his GBA but not the Printer). He is very disappointed that it is not working.

So my question is, is there any way (via a special cable, multiple cables connecting, whatever) to connect a Gameboy Advance to a Gameboy Printer without having to buy another Gameboy/Color?

Comment: I think you just need an adapter for the two cables, or a Game Boy (not Advance).

Comment: What kind of adaptar? Could you provide a link?

Comment: According to [Gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/gba/916598-game-boy-advance/faqs/35200): "The Game Boy Printer is compatible with all versions of the Game Boy. That is, the original Game Boy, the Game Boy Pocket, the Game Boy Color, the Game Boy Advance, and the Game Boy Advance SP."

Comment: @pinckerman But that doesn't solve how to connect them...

Comment: Yes I know, but at least it seems possible

Comment: When I was young I had a gameboy advanced link cable that had a connector for original gameboy and gameboy advanced. Are you able to find anything like that?

Comment: I found it:http://www.amazon.com/Universal-Link-Cable-GameBoy-Game-Boy/dp/B00GKL905O

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a page about the Universal Link Cable on Nintendo's website, when using things designed for Game Boy or Color, use the Universal Link Cable in the GBA, and it does mention the Printer too. So you'd just connect it using the Universal Link Cable.

> **Important Note:** This cable should only be connected when you are playing two player games or when you are **using the Game Boy Printer** with your Game Boy Advance or Game Boy Advance SP.
>   - [Nintendo Customer Service](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/gameboyadvance/hook_universallink.jsp)

Comment: Cool! Can I confirm that the link "Thebluefish" added in the comments is the same cable they are referring to?

Comment: It looks similar, but the cable they're referring to would be the official Universal Link Cable, which I've found on eBay here for a similar price as the third party one "Thebluefish" linked:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Official-Genuine-Nintendo-Game-Boy-Universal-Transfer-Game-Link-Cable-MGB-010/321649192746?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D28772%26meid%3D17ddd6198bc44b30be8eccd1958f5e80%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D221664678579&rt=nc

Comment: Awesome, I'll order it and report back here once i test if it works or not.